# Understanding Oracle's to_date / to_char

Tags: sql, oracle

So I am doing some exercises for myself and I gave myself in a situation with this instructions: (Im in a hospital using their test database)
Displays:

1. `Lname, Fname, Mname, Birth_date, Chief_Complaint, DTTM_ADM` (date/time admission)
2. Then my search would only be between `DTTM_ADM` of `2008` and `2010`
3. Chief complaint will be inputted manually by the user.

I know how to display the 1st and 2nd instructions that I gave myself, but I am having a hard time doing the second instructions. I don't know much about SQL and its other functionality (Which is why I am doing this, to learn).

I was told by my instructor to do the function `to_char` to solve my #2 instruction. Since I am just limiting my search between years (In  their system it is like `01-JUL-14`).

So my question is, how do I do the to_char or to_date in a way i only need to just instruct my search would only be in years and not having a day and month along the limit (Instead of saying the sql `01-JUL-14`, it would be just `2014)`?

```
Table:
PATIENT_ADM A,
PATIENT_ADM B
A.DTTM_ADM > 2008
B.DTTM_ADM < 2010
```

How do I do this properly? (It's kind of hard doing OJT when you only have a limited access to certain website and the net being awfully slow)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by 2 methods,

1. You can use [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) for year comparison as below:

   `PATIENT_ADM A,
   PATIENT_ADM B
   TO_CHAR(A.DTTM_ADM,'YYYY') > '2008' AND
   TO_CHAR(B.DTTM_ADM, 'YYYY') < '2010'`

   **Explanation**, To_Char is used to convert the date into a particular string format say Date only, month only, year only, hours only or Date Month Year with hours seconds etc. Refer the documentation link in answer.
2. You can use [`EXTRACT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm) option for year comparison as below

   `PATIENT_ADM A,
   PATIENT_ADM B
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.DTTM_ADM) > 2008 AND
   EXTRACT(YEAR FROM B.DTTM_ADM) < 2010`

   **Explanation**: Extract is used to extract particular date/time part values from a datefield. This is particularly useful when your DB has large amount of data, since TO_CHAR is slightly costly operation compared to EXTRACT. Refer source document attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE A.DTTM_ADM >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2008', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND
      A.DTTM_ADM <  TO_DATE('01-JAN-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Some notes:-

- I assume that DTTM_ADM is of type `DATE`
- An alternate approach would be to use `TO_CHAR` on `DTTM_ADM`, but this would make indexes on that column unusable by Oracle
- The first condition is a greater than or equal to, incase someone is admitted right on midnight on 01-Jan-2008.
- The second condition is less than, so that if someone is admitted right on midnight on 01-Jan-2011, they are not included in the results

Comment: DTTM IS a type of date which I said you can see above "(date/time admission)". But here's the problem I just want it years only and not include the days and months.

Comment: @NoviceProgrammer My answer finds everything in 2008, 2009 and 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be using `extract()` on your where clause.

`EXTRACT()` to extract and return a year, month, day, hour, minute, second, or time zone from the timestamp types or a DATE.

```
SELECT *
FROM PATIENT_ADM A, PATIENT_ADM
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.DTTM_ADM) > 2008
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM B.DTTM_ADM) < 2010;
```

Answer (score 0):

First find out if DTTM_ADM is of type date or of a character type like varchar2 or char. It should be a date, but as you say "In their system it is like 01-JUL-14", they may store this in a string.

The function to_char works on dates. to_char(DTTM_ADM,'yyyy') would give you the year as a string ('2009' for instance).

If DTTM_ADM happens to be a string type, then to_char is of no use. You would need the string function SUBSTR instead to get the substring holding the year.